# Dynamically change header names when Iframe content changes from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an html master page template. That page consists of a header, body, and footer. In the body, there is an Iframe. The footer has picture button icons that load different html form pages in the iframe. When I click on a different icon, the iframe content changes to that page.

My question, is how to change the header title when I click the icon?

The Master Page has a header called "Metrics Entry Form". When I click the icons at the footer, the header should dynamically change(e.g. Safety Entry Form, Waste Entry Form, etc).

Can this be done with CSS? Or is Javascript or PHP needed. Thanks

My code is pasted below. Any help is most appreciated.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
      <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/Global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Design.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1 id="h1">Metrics Entry Form</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="iFrameHeight">
         <iframe name="iframe" src="MetricsEntryForm.html" scrolling="auto" id="GlobalFrame"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">&nbsp;        
         <input title="Previous Page" type="previousbutton" onclick="PreviousPage()"></input>
         <input title="Waste Entry Page" type="wastebutton" onclick="WastePage()"></input>
         <input title="Metrics Initializer" type="gearbutton" onclick="MetricsPage()"></input>
         <input title="Safety Entry" type="safetybutton" onclick="SafetyEntryPage()"></input>
         <input title="Trending" type="trendbutton" onclick="Trending()"></input>
         <input title="Alarm and Events" type="alarmbutton" onclick="Alarm()"></input>
         <input title="Report Expert" type="expertbutton" onclick="ReportExpert()"></input>
         <input title="Data Entry Reports" type="ssrsbutton" onclick="DataEntrSSRS()"></input>   
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function PreviousPage() {
    window.history.back()
}
function WastePage() {
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "Waste Page";
    document.getElementById("GlobalFrame").src = "WasteEntryForm.html";
}
function SafetyEntryPage() {
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "Safety Page";
    document.getElementById("GlobalFrame").src = "SafetyEntryForm.html";
}
function MetricsPage() {
    document.getElementById("GlobalFrame").src = "MetricsEntryForm.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each function, before you change the iframe's src attribute just set the text of the h1 inside your #header

Like this

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

Comment: like this??? function SafetyEntryPage() {
 document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";
    document.getElementById("GlobalFrame").src = "SafetyEntryForm.html";
}

Comment: I tried this but it didnt src the page  nor did it change the header

Comment: yes, then just change the id to your header id, and the text to what you want it to say.

Comment: I tried labeling the header with the ID h1 and put the line of code before the script but when I publish it wont source to the pages anymore. Something is stopping it from changing headers and content in the iframe

Comment: check this codepen out that does what you are looking for
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbXwBb